# PHP SQL Pagination

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pagination

I can't seem to get the desired result from this query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM `messages` 
   WHERE `msgType` = '0' 
     AND `status` = '0' 
ORDER BY `dateSent` DESC LIMIT 20, 0
```

Basically, I'm trying to show 20 results per page, but this query returns nothing. (For the record, all instances in the database have msgType and status as 0)

**EDIT:** Removing the LIMIT part gives me the results but not divided and paginated like I want

**EDIT v2** LIMIT should be followed by OFFSET, # OF RECORDS (I am dumb)

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LIMIT 20, 0
```

Means: start at row 21, return 0 rows, so your answer is correct.

Did you mean:

```
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: The offset is zero based, but that is the issue here

Comment: There are a total of 24 records. When I do LIMIT 1,20 it gives me records 23, 22, 21, 20....4

Comment: You are totally correct, a some collision in my brain for some reason, I'll edit accordingly..

Comment: @st4ck0v3rfl0w: You're not the first to get parameters backwards - I prefer questions like these to the denormalized data models...

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the single quotes from around your 0's?

Comment: Most databases do implicit conversion between INT and string/VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

It took Cthulhu's answer to jog my memory - the issue is the LIMIT clause.

In MySQL, when LIMIT takes two parameters - the first is the offset, meaning which row it starts from, where the first row is zero.  So:

```
LIMIT 20, 0
```

...will start on the 21st row, and return... zero rows from that point.

You need to reverse the values to get anything back:

```
LIMIT 0, 20
```

...to get the first 20 rows.

Comment: I am dumb. It's official. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What results do you get when removing the limit? Simplify, even if the query is already simple to begin with. Break the problem up into parts.

- How many rows are in the DB matching the conditions?
- What is the datatype of msgType and status?
- What happens when you remove the limit?

Comment: All rows match the conditions. Datatype of msgType and status is varchar. When I remove the limit, it provides the results in time sequence starting from the latest